# ZingGrid CRUD sending request to local apis

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

any body who can help me out, about zingGrid, if possible please provide me sample project,
i wanna know how to send api call using ZIngGrid,

Comment: For future questions, please keep in mind that you need to show some effort. I was able to find something in the GitHub, maybe that is a better place to start your research journey next time.

Comment: I found example [here](https://github.com/ZingGrid/zinggrid/blob/master/examples/index.html) and [here](https://github.com/ZingGrid/zinggrid-react-example).

Answer (score 0):

I spent a reasonable long amount of time to get the inbuilt ZingGrid api to do CRUD operations. I found it relatively easy to get the info from the [docs](https://www.zinggrid.com/docs), but the Api seemed to strict or silly and homogeneous to be customised for my purpose. 
By silly or strict I don't mean to say that ZingGrids are not an excellent Api, I just mean that for instance if you add a `type="select"` column and you select a column the ZingGrid suddenly counts the selected rows and a `delete` button appears (I haven't tested but I believe this can be overridden by adding a custom function to the `onselect` method, but why add a delete button?); or if you set the `src="url"` attribute on the `zg-data` tag all Api calls use that url, which I do not understand since the `zg-data` is to populate with GET requests the table (I believe createOptions could override this, but I could not get it to work).  
I contacted the ZingGrid developers but they seemed more interested in me buying a package with support that contains a link inside the package that they can query to see if my clients are using a licensed product.  Why? Don't they trust their clients. In our budget there was actually money allocated for a ZingGrid license, but a link-free one.   
So given the time I spent testing if ZingGrids are a viable option I used the inbuilt [methods](https://www.zinggrid.com/docs/api/methods/reference) and [events](https://www.zinggrid.com/docs/api/events/reference) from the free version to get the data and then send the requests via fetch - and/or XmlHttpRequest Api.

```
// Get ZingGrid table element reference
const zgRefTableA = document.querySelector("zing-grid#zgRefTableA");

// Bind function to executeOnload() method
zgRefTableA.executeOnLoad(function() {
    // Get grid data
    zgRefTableA.addEventListener('row:click', function(e) {
        const data = e.detail.ZGData.data; // row data
        fnFetch(data.url, "PUT", data);
    });
});

fnFetch(action /* string url path */, method /* string http request method */,
        data /* object form data */, timesOut = 45000 /* int timeout in milliseconds */) {
    // headers
    const pHeader = {
        method: method, // method string
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // body json
        headers: {
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector('input[name="guest_csrf_token"]').value
        }
    };
        
    // timeout promise
    const timeouts = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { // add timeout promise
        setTimeout(resolve, timesOut, {timeout: true});
    });
        
    // DO: Fetch
    return Promise.race([
        fetch(action, pHeader), timeouts
    ])
    .then(response => {
        if ( response.timeout !== undefined && response.timeout ) {
            throw new Error('timeout');
        } else if( response.ok ) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error(`${response.status} ${response.statusText}`); 
        }
    })
    .then(data => {
        // handle data ...
    })
    .catch(err => { 
        // handle error ...
    });
}
```

I also integrated the free version ZingGrids with backend Laravel, which was quite cool.

Of course above example only sends the data via fetch, you could first populate a form and then send the data with fetch, or try ZingGrid inbuilt attributes `editor-controls` or `editor` or the tag `zg-dialog`.